# Bug in constexpr function MSVC E0028 "attempt to access expired storage"?

Tags: c++

I have some `constexpr` code that compiles and executes with MSVC, CLANG, and GCC. However, in Visual Studio 2022 latest, it places red squiggles under the function with the following (intellisense?) error listed:

"E0028 expression must have a constant value" This is followed by "attempt to access expired storage" followed by 6 lines that all are: "called from"

The problem is associated with the `add()` method when using the `vector::insert()`. It goes away if I use an alternate algorithm that doesn't use `insert`.

Here's what the squiggles look like:

[image: Showing red squiggles]

What is causing this? The code this subset is from compiles cleanly

Here's the full code with the problem narrowed down to just `vector::insert`.

```
#include <vector>

constexpr int foo()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{ 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int> v2{ 1,2,3 };
    v2.insert(v2.end(), v1.begin(), v1.end());
    return v2[5];
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int a = foo();  // intellisense squiggle here
}
```

Comment: The red squiggles are from intellisense. Think of it like a compiler that's allowed to be wrong in order to be superfast. Sometimes it's just wrong, and the newer the syntax you feed it, the more likely there are going to be missed edge cases.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly declare the copy ctor and copy assignment operator as constexpr? For me this makes the difference

Comment: @vikAy Yep. The code it's from which is a 2D matrix set has all those defined. Seems to be related to the `insert` method.

Comment: @user4581301 any way to disable that particular intelliense stuff? It's very annoying.

Comment: Might be something in tools-> options. Expand Text Editor->C/C++ and Click Advanced. Butt load of intellisense tuning options in that properties pane. Other than that, I dunno.

Comment: I think intellisense isn't aware of all  things that became valid in C++20. The code was invalid pre C++20 and that's probably what it's complaining about. Just ignore it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused. _"Non-literal variables (and labels and gotos) in `constexpr` functions"_ [P2242R3](https://wg21.link/P2242R3) is accepted for inclusion in C++23 - but all the mentioned compilers accepts the code in C++20 mode.

Comment: @TedLyngmo MS ahead of the curve for once?

Comment: @PaulSanders They all are it seems. In the paper they mention that this is considered an improvement, a consistency bug fix, so perhaps compiler creators just threw it into C++20 too :-)

Comment: @PaulSanders they've been ahead others since C++14

Comment: Wow @phuclv, you're sticking your neck out there! :)

Comment: @PaulSanders that's not something I watched, but stackoverflowers and cppreference people already did that